# Java memory consuming is high and growing

Tags: java, memory

I have a Spring Boot REST service that moves files from a folder into a ZIP archive every minute and upload the archive to another service. My service keeps a map of zipped files and zip name using Cache2K and HSQLDB. Another application uses the service to register the created files and later asks for the name of the zip in which the files was located.

The service is running on Windows Server 2019 Standard 32GB RAM with starting parameters

`java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxMetaSpaceSize=128MB -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail`

result of `jcmd 1234 VM.native_memory`

*after 1min of running:* **total=1122461KB**, **commited=728301KB**, task manager shows **used=534MB**

*after week of running:* **total=1137792KB**, **commited=749376KB**, but task manager shows **used=8GB**

Why is used/reserved memory so high?

Fight recorder do not shows any problems, GC runs well. I tried updating Oracle Java 8 to OpenJDK 11, updating Spring Boot to newer version, nothing helps. Memory consume growing seems to be linear.

Comment: Which expiration time do you set for your _cache2k_ `Cache` entries? If your entries never expire the `Cache` will hold a reference to your entries forever and therefore the GC will never free this memory.

Comment: cache item expiration is 10 minutes, incoming speed of new files is 20/minute, every file (cache item) is requested for 3-5 minutes.

Comment: I'm not convinced there's a problem. Anyway, the most common thing would be an unclosed file or IO stream. Do make double-sure you're using try-with-resources everywhere you should. One surprising place is calls like `Files.newDirectoryStream()` or `Files.find()`. Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer to see which files your process holds. If it's all the zip files or anything else unexpected, there's your leak. Also, `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=datail` should be `detail`, you have a typo in yours.

Comment: sounds like you have a memory leak

Comment: thanks, "datail" was just typu there. ProcesExplorer shows growing HandlesCountm one handle per second. Really, I found `Files.newDirectoryStream()` and `Files.walk` without try-with-resources in my code. Code fixed and handles ocsilating about 730-750. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

`Files.newDirectoryStream()` and `Files.walk` enclosed with `try-with-resources`.

Thanks [Petr Janeček](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1273080/petr-jane%C4%8Dek)

*P.S. after a week of service running, memory consumption is stable*

Comment: Nice. That actually is a common problem. Feel free to add a tick to your answer as it is the correct one. And let me know in a week if the mem usage / opened files count is stable now!

Answer (score 0):

Try the  `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize`  parameter if off-heap memory is used

Comment: ok I try, but MaxDirectMemorySize should be equal to Xmx by default

Comment: Why do you say that?  The manual entry says: *"By default, the size is set to 0, meaning that the JVM chooses the size for NIO direct-buffer allocations automatically."*.  There is no mention of `-Xmx` in that.

Comment: Because I saw him say he did file manipulation, and it was a gut feeling